# How to import codes beginning with "0" from CSV to SAS as strings?

Tags: csv, import, sas, proc

I've been trying to import in SAS a variable of codes starting with a "0" from a csv file, but the "0" at the beginning disappears (for instance "01111" becomes "1111" in SAS).

The problem is that SAS always imports this variable as a numeric variable when using proc import. I know the problem could be solved using "infile". The thing is I would like to avoid using "infile" and the data step, because I have many variables and all the others are imported correctly.

Do you have any idea how to do this ?

I've tried the DBDSOPTS function but it doesn't seem to work:

```
proc import out=out.data
datafile="&path./datafile.csv" 
dbms=csv
replace;
getnames=yes;
delimiter=";";
DBDSOPTS= "DBTYPE=(var1='CHAR(3)')";
run;
```

NB: I cannot concatenate the code with a "0" (ex: cat("0",var1)) because some codes start with other numbers (ex: 12000).

Comment: What happens when you run your code (errors in log?).  I don't use PROC IMPORT, but maybe try `DBDSOPTS= "DBSASTYPE=(var1='CHAR(3)')";` ?

Comment: It says " Statement is not valid or it is used out of proper order " even with your suggestion

Comment: Ahh, that's why I didn't see it in the documentation, I guess. Maybe it's not part of the dbms=csv engine.  I think when it reads a CSV, PROC IMPORT shows the DATA step code it generates in the log.  So you could always copy that code, and update the informat used for the problematic variable. I tend to think of PROC IMPORT as useful for "quick-and-dirty" reads, but not production work.

Comment: Are the values a fixed width that's padded with zeros? If so, you can add them back with a format.

Comment: You could use another tool to guess how to read the CSV file.  For example https://github.com/sasutils/macros/blob/master/csv2ds.sas will attach the Z format to variables it determines are integers with some values starting with 0.  It also has a method for you to override its guess about the variable metadata.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are concerned about how PROC IMPORT guessed to read your file then write the code to read it yourself.  You could use the code PROC IMPORT generated as a guide.